# Getting error when using *ngIf with else in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

Here is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title:string = 'angularapp';

public username:string='root';
public password:string='root';

}
```

Here is my app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="username=='root' && password=='root'; else elseBlock">

  <h3>Login suceess</h3>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <h3>Login failed</h3>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

I have get an error when add else elseBlock to *ngIf
here is the error

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:1:56 - error TS2339: Property 'elseBlock' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

1 <div *ngIf="username=='root' && password=='root'; else elseBlock">
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elseBlock cannot be inside the block managed by *ngIf.
The correct template should look like this :

```
<div *ngIf="username=='root' && password=='root'; else elseBlock">

  <h3>Login suceess</h3>


</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <h3>Login failed</h3>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not even have ngIf. You can solve it using ternary operators:

```
<h3> 
  {{ ((username === 'root') && (password === 'root')) ? 'Login success' : 'Login failed'
</h3>
```